# Matlab containers.map strange key behaviour with SerialDateNumber

Tags: matlab, datetime, dictionary, key, containers

The following code uses Matlabs Serial Date Number as a key in matlabs container map.  The key type is double.  Is this correct?  Can Matlabs Serial Date Number be used as a key?

```
    currDateTime='2013-02-12 11:00';
     dateNum=datenum(currDateTime);
    keySet =   {dateNum};
    currentDateNum=datestr(dateNum);
    valueSet = {currentDateNum} ;



    weatherFrontMap = containers.Map(keySet,valueSet);

     weatherFrontMap(dateNum)='eleven';
     currDateTime='2013-02-12 12:00';
     dateNum=datenum(currDateTime);
     weatherFrontMap(dateNum)='twelve';
     currDateTime='2013-02-12 13:00';
     dateNum=datenum(currDateTime);
     weatherFrontMap(dateNum)='thirteen';


    currentDateNum=datestr(dateNum);
    disp (currentDateNum)
    str=weatherFrontMap(dateNum);
    disp(str)


     subtractHour=addtodate(dateNum,-1,'hour');
     currentDateNum=datestr(subtractHour);
    disp (currentDateNum)

     strSubtractHour=weatherFrontMap(subtractHour);
     disp(strSubtractHour)


     subtractHour2=addtodate(dateNum,-2,'hour');
      currentDateNum=datestr(subtractHour2);
    disp (currentDateNum)

     strSubtractHour2=weatherFrontMap(subtractHour2);
     disp(strSubtractHour2)
```

This prints:

12-Feb-2013 13:00:00

thirteen

12-Feb-2013 12:00:00

twelve

12-Feb-2013 11:00:00

Error using containers.Map/subsref

The specified key is not present in this container.

Error in testMap (line 40)

strSubtractHour2=weatherFrontMap(subtractHour2);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floating point numbers aren't a good fit to a map container as testing equality on with floating point numbers is risky (due to the imprecise storage of floating point numbers).

This code would work better if you used a string representation of the date/time where you can control the precision.